# Can a boxed value type be distinguished from a reference type without Reflection

Tags: .net, struct, boxing

If one has a routine which takes a parameter of type `IEnumerator<string>`, is there any way via which it can distinguish between a reference to a class-type instance and a reference to a boxed value-type instance?  I know that if one has a routine like:

```
void DoSomething<T>(T param) where T:IEnumerator
```

it's possible to tell whether `T` is a value type or a reference type without using reflection by simply doing `Object.ReferenceEquals(param, param)`.  That will always return true if `T` is a class type, and always return false if it is a value type (it can't be a nullable value type, since it implements an interface).  On the other hand, if one were to call `DoSomething<IEnumerator<string>>(myListOfStrings.GetEnumerator())` I don't know any way that `DoSomething` would be able to, without using Reflection, distinguish the behavior of the boxed `IEnumerator<string>` from that of any other class type.  Is there any non-Reflection-related way in which the behavior of boxed value types differs from that of class types?

**Addendum**

To clarify the question, suppose I have a struct `S1` which implements `IFoo`, and I have a class `C1` which implements the same interface, and has precisely the same methods and fields.  If one has an variable of declared type `IFoo`, is there any way in which the 'natural' behavior of a boxed`S1` instance referenced by that variable would differ from that of a `C1` referenced likewise *other than the fact that GetType() will of course return different `Type` objects*?

Comment: Personally, I'd just use something involving typeof(T).IsValueType. Maybe caching the result in a static generic class if I absolutely needed...

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid reflection? Also, your code wouldn't compile. Did you mean `DoSomething<IEnumerator<string>>(myListOfStrings.GetEnumerator())`?

Comment: @svick: IEnumeratable changed to IEnumerator.  Thanks.  Updating question to clarify a little more.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an object `e` whose static type is some interface (like `IEnumerator<string>`) and you want to know whether it's a boxed value type, you can simply use:

```
e is ValueType
```

[`System.ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) is common base class of all value types in .Net.

Comment: The corner case here is a struct that implements IEnumerable.  Took me a while to see why `IEnumerator<string>` was quoted, always a ref type.  +1 for the prettiest answer, it hides the form of reflection that the *is* operator uses pretty well.  It is the fast kind, the odds that the type info is unmapped are low.

Comment: @HansPassant: My question is how the *behavior* of a boxed struct would differ from that of a class with the same fields and methods, other than the fact the system says one is a value type and the other a class type.  Non-boxed value types behave very differently from class types, but boxed value-type instances ones behave exactly like class types in every way I can identify, other than the return value for `GetType`.  What other differences are there?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The act of boxing is pretty massive all by itself.  A complete copy of the struct gets embedded into a chunk of memory that has to be allocated from the GC heap.  What happens next is pretty minor compared to that.  After all, now it's a class object that doesn't get treated very differently from a regular reference type object.

Comment: @HansPassant: Creating a struct and boxing it is apt to be a little slower than creating a class instance, though I would expect that for simple structs/classes the additional time would be minor compared to the amortized GC time associated with creating a new class instance and hastening the next garbage collection.  My question is in what cases, if any, the recipient of a boxed struct might observe any behavior that was unexpectedly different from that of a class which had exactly the same methods and fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Type.IsValueType` property. Here is an example:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        DoSomething(10);            // True
        DoSomething((object)10);    // True
        DoSomething(new Random());  // False
    }

    public static void DoSomething<T>(T arg)
    {
        bool isValueType = arg.GetType().IsValueType;
        Console.WriteLine(isValueType);
    }
```

Comment: Type.IsValueType entails Reflection, does it not?

Comment: @supercat: it will walk up the type hierarchy (using `Type.BaseType` property) and check if the parent is of type `(Type)RuntimeType.ValueType`. At that moment all base Type objects will be already loaded into the AppDomain, so this approach doesn't seem to introduce any performance impacts.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear in my question, since I consider `GetType()`, and just about everything having to do with explicitly-referenced `Type` objects, to be Reflection.  The question was not intended to be one of performance, but semantics.  The behavior of an unboxed structures will be markedly different from that of a class with the same methods and fields.  Given a boxed structure, however, and a class with the same methods and fields, would there be any way to distinguish them other than via `GetType()`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be considered a "visible difference", but I think it's notable that when a struct is boxed twice, the two boxed objects will not be reference-equal. This makes sense because structs don't have a sense of reference-identity. I don't think this is likely to come up, though.

My example below is pretty contrived.

```
public class BoxDemo
{
    public interface IFoo { }
    public class CFoo : IFoo { }
    public struct SFoo : IFoo { }

    public static class TestBoxing
    {
        public static void dotest()
        {
            CFoo C = new CFoo();
            SFoo S = new SFoo();

            Debug.WriteLine(IsBoxedStruct(C, C)); // writes "false"
            Debug.WriteLine(IsBoxedStruct(S, S)); // writes "true"
        }

        public static bool IsBoxedStruct(IFoo f1, IFoo f2)
        {
            return !object.ReferenceEquals(f1, f2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a third declaration `IFoo I = new SFoo()`; and then `Debug.WriteLine(IsBoxedStruct(I, I));`  What is being tested by passing a parameter twice is not whether the called function receives boxed structures, but rather whether the caller has non-boxed structures.

Comment: Incidentally, it's very difficult for a value-type instance method to determine whether `this` refers to a particular boxed instance, and I know of no way for a value-type instance to determine whether `this` is boxed.